# How to downloaded from remote location and execute script on container start Docker?

Tags: bash, shell, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run similar script for few different images in docker-compose environment. Modifying and pushing all images using similar Dockerfiles would be difficult, so I'm looking for an alternative solution.

In docker-compose I can change only entrypoint and command. So I'm looking for a way to execute script downloaded from remote location as an entrypoint.

Simply saying I want to execute command `sh <(wget -qO- http://localhost/script.sh) arg` or `wget -qO- http://localhost/script.sh | sh -s arg` as entrypoint, but can't find a way how it should be done.

Comment: Why isn't `sh <(wget -qO- http://localhost/script.sh) arg` useful to you? I struggle to understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: @fedorqui this command doesn't work if executed as entrypoint of docker container or I can't find a way to do it correctly.